# PySide: passing data from QML to Python

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside, qtdeclarative

I'm trying to send data from QML to Python, but I'm getting an error.

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtDeclarative

class Test( QtCore.QObject ):
    def __init__( self ):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def printText(self,text):
        print text

class MainWindow( QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( MainWindow, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setWindowTitle( "Test" )
        self.setSource( QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile( './test.qml' ) )
        self.setResizeMode( QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView )

app = QtGui.QApplication( sys.argv )
window = MainWindow()
context = window.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty("testModel",Test())
window.show()
sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

test.qml:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "white"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        color: "black"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "click"
            color: "white"
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                testModel.printText("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, I expected it to print "test" but instead I get this error:

> TypeError: printText() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

What am I missing?

*EDIT: changed the example to a simpler one.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to specify the slot's argument type. Fixed it by changing the declaration of printText() to this:

```
@QtCore.Slot('QString')
def printText(self,text):
    print text
```

Comment: Since QString has been removed, I think this would be better now: @QtCore.Slot(str) or @QtCore.Slot(unicode)